# is stable rc same as stable?

Tags: release-odin

Is stable release candidate (early access) just stable ?
If not then after official release will I be able to update ?

I really want to start using it as my daily but idk if it's the full version

Comment: I think it is.. probably stable release will be the same or just little modified release candidate build

Comment: Release Candidate versions are close to stable releases but there may be bugs. However, talking about elementaryOS, you won't be able to update between versions. You would need to do a full system install.